# Angular not converting unix dates as it should

Tags: angularjs

I am getting very strange data from the dates, and I just cannot see why?!?

```
<b>{{ (lines.date*1000) | date:"dd-mm-yyyy" }}: </b>
```

Here is the data in my lines array:

```
   "lines" : [
        {
            "text" : "was CREATED Tue Jul 11 2017 from Booking.com: ThaiHome by ThaiHome Staff", 
            "date" : 1499754031
        }, 
        {
            "date" : 1499754031, 
            "text" : "wrote message: This is the message the NEW user writes to manager"
        }, 
        {
            "date" : 1499754140, 
            "text" : "wrote message: This is the message the NEW user writes to manager"
        }, 
        {
            "date" : 1499754140, 
            "text" : "wrote message: This is the message the NEW user writes to manager"
        },
```

And here is the output

```
11-20-2017:   was CREATED Tue Jul 11 2017 from Booking.com: ThaiHome by ThaiHome Staff
11-20-2017:   wrote message: This is the message the NEW user writes to manager
11-22-2017:   wrote message: This is the message the NEW user writes to manager
11-22-2017:   wrote message: This is the message the NEW user writes to manager
11-22-2017:   wrote message: This is the message the NEW user writes to manager
11-24-2017:   wrote message: This is the message the NEW user writes to manager
11-24-2017:   wrote message: This is the message the NEW user writes to manager
11-24-2017:   wrote message: This is the message the NEW user writes to manager
```

Why am I getting these strange dates instead of getting the usual real dates?

Answer (score 3):

Small `mm` is for minute in hour, padded (00-59). For month you can use one of the below:

- `MMMM`: Month in year (January-December)
- `MMM`: Month in year (Jan-Dec)
- `MM`: Month in year, padded (01-12)
- `M`: Month in year (1-12)

[Official reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: Noooo really?? hahaha damn! - I been sweating over this one for an hour trying to solve it with math hahah.   I need to look better at the tokens it accepts :-)   Thanks Prerak :-D

Comment: Happy to help :)